# on duplicate key update в pymysql или сломай голову работая в Python

Tags: mysql, python, pymysql

Подскажите как можно сделать `on duplicate key update` через `pymysql` на питоне

```
import pymysql
import time

conn = pymysql.connect(host='host', user='user', password='pass', db='db',charset='cp1251', autocommit=True)
a = conn.cursor()
nt = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

photo = ..............  #какие-то данные
text = ..........  #какие-то данные
idgrp = .......  #какие-то данные

a.execute("INSERT INTO `vtip` (`idgroup`, `img`, `text`, `time`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (idgrp, photo, text, nt))
```

Мне нужно сделать `on duplicate key update` что бы в случае дубля мне обновляло лишь время `nt`

Пытался сделать:

```
a.execute("INSERT INTO `vtip` (`idgroup`, `img`, `text`, `time`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) on duplicate key update `time` = %s", (idgrp, photo, text, nt), %s)
```

но не получается

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: а что именно не получается? какое сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: А что за %s в самом конце третьим параметром ? И в массиве значений должно быть столько же, сколько %s в запросе. Или в запросе не дублируйте %s а пишите `update time=values(time),...`

Comment: Да, по-моему, @Mike очень точно подметил надо заменить: `(idgrp, photo, text, nt), %` --> `(idgrp, photo, text, nt, nt)`

Comment: `Мне нужно сделать on duplicate key update что бы в случае дубля мне обновляло лишь время nt` - уж не на текущее ли?

Comment: Попробуйте: `a.execute('INSERT INTO vtip (idgroup,img,text,time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,now()) on duplicate key update time = now()"', (idgrp, photo, text))`

Answer (score 0):

> a.execute('INSERT INTO vtip (idgroup,img,text,time) VALUES
>   (%s,%s,%s,now()) on duplicate key update time = now()"', (idgrp,
>   photo, text))